# How to improve the foreground extraction using cv2.grabcut

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation, background-subtraction

[Foreground-extraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtgNd.jpg)

I am extracting a person from its background and I am using cv2.grabcut for that. But sometimes the background pixels are misclassified as foreground hence the extraction is not perfect. I have attached the resultant image. How to improve this extraction?

Comment: You should provide the original image and minimal reproducing code. Otherwise we can only provide a few tips.

Answer (score 1):

To improve the extraction you need to play with `iterCount` and `mode` parameters.

- For instance:

---

I have the following image:

---

[image]

- If I apply the [example code](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html):

  ---

[image]

- Can I improve by changing the `iterCount`?

  - iterCount=10, 20 (respectively)

  ---

  [image][image]

  - iterCount = 30, 40 (respectively)

  ---

  [image][image]
- Can I improve by changing the modes?

  ---

  mode = `GC_INIT_WITH_RECT`, `GC_INIT_WITH_MASK` (respectively)

  [image] [image]

In my case `GC_INIT_WITH_MASK` works good, but I said you need to change parameters until the satisfactory result comes out.

Comment: Based on the code you provided, the mask was manually created using paint. I am looking for something that doesnt require manual intervention

Comment: You don't have to use GC_INIT_WITH_MASK, maybe GC_INIT_WITH_RECT works better

Comment: I am using GC_INIT_WITH_RECT only, as I am detecting the person through object detection and passing its coordinates to the grabcut for extraction